# Excel VBA and SQL to inner join ODBC table and Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, adodb, plsqldeveloper

I am really hoping this can be accomplished. Basically, I have a routine that queries an view I have created in Oracle SQL Developer. However, the entire view has thousands of more rows than I need and I want to pull just a subset based on a list of part numbers I have within the same Excel file, but everything I have tried results in errors.

Here's the code right now:

```
--Create Connection and Recordset objects
Set odmConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set odmRec = New ADODB.Recordset
odmConn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
odmConn.CommandTimeout = 0
odmRec.CursorLocation = adUseClient

--Open Connection
odmConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=ODBCServer;UID=MyID;PWD=MyPass;"

--Define SQL string and sheet name
strSQL = "SELECT A.* " & _
         "FROM MyID.MyTable A" & _
         "INNER JOIN " & _
         "(SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=MyExcelPath].[MAT$]) B" & _
         "ON A.MATERIAL = B.MATERIAL"
shName = "MySheet"

--Extract new data to Recordset
odmRec.Open strSQL, odmConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

If odmRec.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    --Copy new data from Recordset
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shName).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset odmRec
End If
```

The above results in an "ORA-00903: invalid table name" error.

I have also tried OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE to no avail. Both of these result in an error that says either "missing right parenthesis" or "SQL command not properly ended."

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You cannot run that query to connect to Excel workbooks. It is only supported in the MS Access ACE SQL dialect not other dialects like Oracle.

Comment: You cannot join an Oracle table with an Excel sheet. You need to make two select statements (one to Oracle and one to Excel) and join the results with a loop.

Comment: The role of the ODBC driver is not to execute this statement but to pass the statement to the backend (Oracle). It will pass the inner Select-statement as statement, and the Oracle engine of course does not know anything about your Excel. If your list in Excel is short, you can try to create an `IN-Clause` to fetch only material you need.

Comment: Thank you all for the information. 
@WernfriedDomscheit, if I do make two select statements, how would I join them after? Can I just inner join to RecordSets?

Comment: @FunThomas That's what I usually do, but this time, the subset of part numbers exceeds the 1000 character limit.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no 1000 char limit but an 1000 item limit. There are workaround for that. Alternative is to loop over your material numbers and execute one statement per material. This will be slower because you need a round trip to the database per material, but when you use an ADODB.Parameter to pass the material, it shoudn't be that bad.

Comment: If your SQL table is the larger one then the best is to create a temp table using Excel data, join them inside Oracle and return the result to Excel